# window.onload not working after page load in chrome developer console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, window.location

window.onload doesn't seem to run the specified function in the chrome console and I can't seem to find anyone with the solution.

Code:

```
function preStart() {
    console.log("Hello");
}
window.location = 'https://www.google.com/';
window.onload = preStart; //Please note, adding brackets here doesn't fix the problem
```

When ran the window.location successfully runs but "preStart" does not.
I realize that `window.onload` doesn't work after `window.location` but is there a solution to this? (Where the function runs after the page loads)

Since I am relatively new to JavaScript please explain any answers/solutions.

Any help with this would me much appreciated.

Note - I have tried `setTimeout` with the following and it still doesn't work:

```
function preStart() {
console.log("Hello");
}
window.location = 'https://www.google.com/';
setTimeout(preStart,2000);
```

Comment: Avoid doing redirections in your code if you are simply testing functions

Comment: @charlietfl This is for a bigger project where code needs to be executed on multiple web pages. (There maybe an easier way of doing this that I can't think of)

Answer (score 2):

Your onLoad method is fine, but you are canceling it by changing the window.location before it is run.
Try adding the window.location at the end of the preStart() method to ensure your script is run before the change of window location cancels it:

```
function preStart() {
    console.log("Hello");
    window.location = 'https://www.google.com/';
}
window.onload = preStart;
```

Also, the console is cleared on a new page load, so even if you do have "hello" printed, you might not get the chance to see it. Try using alert("hello") to check if code is being executed instead:

```
function preStart() {
    alert("hello");
    window.location = 'https://www.google.com/';
}
window.onload = preStart;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. No matter which order I write the code in it always does the `alert("Hello")` or the `console.log("Hello")` before loading the web page. I want this to occur after the web page has loaded.

Comment: @M.P.Tree I suspect you are dealing with other content loaded after `onload` using javascript if what you are looking for doesn't exist within `onload` callback. At that point all resources with the page source have loaded...images, scripts, css etc

Comment: calling window.location unloads the current web page, and you can not run any scrips from an unloaded web page, so unfortunately I don't think it's possible to run scripts from a previous web page once you've already loaded a new one

Comment: Well you could kindly ask google to put your function on their site for you. Think about it, man!